# What exactly is Microsoft 365 going to support?

Tags: adoption

I read [an announcement](http://www.newsbtc.com/2017/01/01/microsoft-office-bitcoin-support/) that Excel in the upcoming Microsoft 365 is going to support Bitcoin "recognition" and "calculations". What does that mean?

Answer (score 7):

Presumably, this means that if you type '0.5 BTC' into a cell, it will be recognized as an amount of money instead of text. (Currently, if you type '$5' into a cell, it will recognize this as an amount of money.) You will probably be able to write formulas that manipulate Bitcoin amounts, which could be useful if you wanted to sum all of the Bitcoin amounts in a column.